# Where to put .fadein() in ajax pagination

Tags: php, html, ajax, pagination

I done ajax pagination (by watching tutorial) but now i need to add fadein effect and i cant figure how. I tried to add `.fadeIn()` probably everywhere but it wont work and i dont know where to put it. What i want to do is smooth page change.

Here is my script i think i dont need to add php.
And i have only back and next options. Not numbers of sites.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //showing the data without refresh but on going to next pagination
    setTimeout(function(){
        load_fn_data();
        }, 1000);

    function load_fn_data(page){
        $.ajax({
            url:"data.php",
            method:"POST",
            data: {
                page:page
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#load_data').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
        $(document).on('click','.pagination_link',function(){
            var page = $(this).attr("id");
            load_fn_data(page);
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide before, than `.html` and afterwards `.fadeIn()` on *success* like:

```
function load_fn_data(page){

    $('#load_data').hide()

    $.ajax({
        url:"data.php",
        method:"POST",
        data: {
            page:page
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('#load_data').html(data).fadeIn(800);
        }
    });
}
```